# js json how to fetch value from json and pass the value to other json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have small issue in passing the value of one json to other json. Below is the list if JSON objects.

```js
var inputArray = [{
  "QUANTITY": 16,
  "NAME": "RAM",
  "fromDate": "01-May-2019",
  "toDate": "08-May-2019"
}, {
  "QUANTITY": 18,
  "NAME": "RAM",
  "fromDate": "09-May-2019",
  "toDate": "15-May-2019"
}, {
  "QUANTITY": 11,
  "NAME": "RAM",
  "fromDate": "16-May-2019",
  "toDate": "22-May-2019"
}, {
  "QUANTITY": 61,
  "NAME": "RAM",
  "fromDate": "23-May-2019",
  "toDate": "31-May-2019"
}, {
  "QUANTITY": 50,
  "NAME": "Syam",
  "fromDate": "23-May-2019",
  "toDate": "31-May-2019"
}]
```

I need to pass `QUANTITY` from `json1` array to `finalJSON` which looks like below..

```js
var finalArray = [{
  "NAME": "Ram",
  "fromDateOne": "01-May-2019",
  "toDateEight": "08-May-2019",
  "QUANTITY_ONE": "16",
  "fromDateNine": "09-May-2019",
  "toDateFifteen": "15-May-2019",
  "QUANTITY_TWO": "18",
  "fromDateSixteen": "16-May-2019",
  "toDateTwentyTwo": "22-May-2019",
  "QUANTITY_THREE": "11",
  "fromDateTwentyThree": "23-May-2019",
  "toDateThirtyOne": "31-May-2019",
  "QUANTITY_FOUR": "61",
  "TOTAL_QTY": "106"
}, {
  "NAME": "Syam",
  "fromDateOne": "01-May-2019",
  "toDateEight": "08-May-2019",
  "QUANTITY_ONE": "0",
  "fromDateNine": "09-May-2019",
  "toDateFifteen": "15-May-2019",
  "QUANTITY_TWO": "0",
  "fromDateSixteen": "16-May-2019",
  "toDateTwentyTwo": "22-May-2019",
  "QUANTITY_THREE": "0",
  "fromDateTwentyThree": "23-May-2019",
  "toDateThirtyOne": "31-May-2019",
  "QUANTITY_FOUR": "50",
  "TOTAL_QTY": "50"
}];
```

My Final JSON should look like above..

Here if you see in `finalJSON` there are 2 objects. From `json1` first 4 objects with `NAME` **RAM** was in first object of `finalJSON` array.

For 2nd Object of `NAME` **Syam**, only `QUANTITY_FOUR` got updated with value **50**, `QUANTITY_ONE,QUANTITY_TWO,QUANTITY_THREE` should be updated as 0

Actually in my Application there will be thousands of records like `json1` where i need to convert those like `finalJSON`.

Can someone please help me to acheive that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Firstly none of the data structures you've shown are JSON. They are all arrays containing objects. Secondly, do you have any control over the output format? Using properties like `QUANTITY_N`, `fromDateN` and `toDateN` is a terrible idea.

Comment: Your inputArray is not valid - it needs a comma between each definition i.e. inputArray = [{"QUANTITY": 16,....},{"QUANTITY": 16,....},{"QUANTITY": 16,....}]

Comment: @jeff, i apolozise. I edited the question and added commas to my array.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yes i have control on my output format. "finalJSON" is the exact output which im expecting. Can you suggest me a best way to acheive that? Because from backend im getting the data in that format only..